# mount a NAS network share, but let the NAS sleep

Tags: mount, raspberry-pi, git, nas

I have a NAS (WD MyCloud) which has by default NFS/SMB access enabled. I also have a raspberry pi, that I would like to use as a git server that is addressable over internet using a SSH connection. The data would be stored on the NAS.

To sum up:

`Internet -> router -> raspberry -> NAS`

I've managed to mount the NAS share with NFS, but when I do this, the NAS never sleeps since it is mounted by the raspberry pi. I only make a few commits, and it would be better if the NAS is active only when needed.

Is it possible to achieve this using NFS? using another technology? Is it possible to unmount the NFS share after a time and remount it automatically when needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this question on my StackExchange profile. Since then, I found the answer I was looking for:

Instead of doing NFS mounts, I am now using SSHFS to access the files, which gives me encryption and authentication on the NAS.

The public key of the raspberry is saved on the NAS and configured so that I can do a `ssh git@cloud` without entering a password. user `git` must have access to the required folders.

Then, I am using AutoFS on the raspberry to automatically mount the sshfs when needed.

Create `/autofs` mountpoint

```
mkdir /autofs
```

in `/etc/auto.master` (user `git` on the raspberry has UID/GID of 1005/1000, replace accordingly with the UID/GID of the user that will have access to the mountpoint)

```
/autofs /etc/auto.git uid=1005,gid=1000, --timeout=30, --ghost
```

in `/etc/auto.git` (`/nfs/git` is the mountpoint on the cloud server)

```
git -fstype=fuse,port=22,rw,allow_other :sshfs\#git@cloud\:/nfs/git
```

then the `/autofs/git` will point to `/nfs/git` on the server. A service restart may be required to apply these changes, I don't remember very well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the automounter and specify the timeouts that you want.  Then things will be mounted as needed and unmounted after a period of inactivity.